# Auto prepend PHP file using htaccess relative to htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I used:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "file.php"
```

in my `.htaccess` that is in `public_html` folder.

Now when I run `public_html/sub/index.php` i get this error :

```
Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'file.php'
```

How to use `auto_prepend_file` flag to include a file relative to `.htaccess` file ?

Comment: why not use absolute path : /home/user_name/public_html/file.php ?

Comment: @ZulkhaeryBasrul because i don't know what is the absolute path that software is installed.

Comment: Can't you use get_cwd() on the php script to find the absoulute path or $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?

Comment: @MyStream So that's using PHP and I'm trying to use htaccess

Comment: I meant to get the path - not to use that command in your htaccess - just to find the path for inclusion in your .htaccess - sorry for the confusion =].

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The file must be inside PHP's `include_path`. So you must either set the file's directory to be in the `include_path` inside php.ini, or do it in the .htaccess with a `php_value` statement.

```
php_value include_path ".:/path/to/file_directory"
php_value auto_prepend_file "file.php"
```

If you use the above method in .htaccess, be sure to copy the `include_path` from php.ini in and add the `:/path_to/file_directory` so you don't lose any already needed includes.

Alternatively, just add `:/path/to/file_directory` to `include_path` directly in the php.ini

#### Update

If you cannot modify the include_path, you might try specifying a relative path to the `auto_prepend_file`. This should work since the file path sent is processed identically as if it was called with `require()`:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "./file.php"
```

Comment: Can you use an absolute system path? If so, get the current system path - perhaps use phpinfo() to find it - and use that?

Comment: For those working in two environments (development / production). You can easily include two paths, like so: `.:/path/for/development:/path/for/production`.

Answer (score 9):

In your .htaccess

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /auto_prepend_file.php
php_value auto_append_file /auto_append_file.php
```

Next create 2 files in root

1) /auto_append_file.php

```
$appendFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/append.php';
require_once($appendFile);
```

2) /auto_prepend_file.php

```
$prependFile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/prepend.php';
require_once($prependFile);
```

Now it should work on local and live servers irrespective of physical path or website providing each of your websites use the same filenames append.php and prepend.php.

Answer (score 4):

I would also add, that if you don't know the hard relative server paths (as with shared hosting and/or PaaS which generate paths dynamically on reboot/deploy) then you can do this:

```
php_value include_path ./:../:../../:../../../:../../../../
php_value auto_prepend_file "prepend.php"
```

In essence this is Pseudo dynamic method/hack/workaround for achieving a .htaccess relative DOCUMENT_ROOT include (which is NOT possible in Apache) as follows:

```
php_value include_path "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/"
```

For security, in prepend.php, it's then possible to re/declare include path as follows (to whatever appropriate paths fit the application):

```
ini_set('open_basedir',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/':<etc.>);
```

Could also look like the following if the last few directories are predictable:

```
php_value include_path ../../../path/to/www/
php_value auto_prepend_file "prepend.php"
```