# Htaccess absolute path

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is it possible to get the absolut path to my ".htaccess" file?

Im using this to load `init.php` in every file.

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/init.php
```

Is there a way so I don't have to write the absolute path?

Like this, if `init.php` is in the same category as the `.htaccess` file:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file [ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_HTACCESS]/init.php
```

and if that is possible, how do I write that but still go back one directory (Since `init.php` is outside `public_html`, where the `.htaccess` is).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `php_value auto_prepend_file ./init.php`?

Comment: Since `init.php` is included in every file, files in subdirectories cant find it if the path is not absolute.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of "[Auto prepened php file using htaccess relative to htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045445/auto-prepened-php-file-using-htaccess-relative-to-htaccess-file)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with using PHP to create the .htaccess file.

Create a htaccess.php file with all the things you want to put in the htaccess file.

```
php_value auto_prepend_file [INIT]init.php
```

Then create a empty `.htaccess` file with the correct permissions.

Then run the class below and replace [INIT] with the absolute path.

Here is the class to generate the .htaccess file:

```
<?php

    class Install {

        public static function htaccess(){

            $file = ".htaccess";

            ob_start();

                include "htaccess.php";
                $htaccess = ob_get_contents();

            ob_end_clean();

            $absolute = __DIR__;
            $init = $absolute;

            $init = str_replace("public_html", "", $init);

            $htaccess = str_replace("[INIT]", $init, $htaccess);

            $opFile = fopen($file, 'w');

            file_put_contents($file, $htaccess, FILE_APPEND);

            fclose($opFile);

        }

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the updated response on the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045445/auto-prepened-php-file-using-htaccess-relative-to-htaccess-file) works, and that your relative directory structure is as you describe:

```
[docroot]
 |
 \- init.php
 |
 \- public_html
     |
     \- .htaccess
     |
     \- index.php
```

then you should be able to go up one directory to the `init.php` file you wish to prepend by including the directive

```
php_value auto_prepend_file ./../init.php
```

in your .htaccess file.

Comment: Not really. The relative path is relative to the PHP file being executed, not to the .htaccess file in question. So this works only if all PHP files are at the same directory level. It might be extended to work in case they are not.