# Variable in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How to set some variable in .htaccess, this part of .htaccess:

```
# Prepend the file
php_value auto_prepend_file "/home/admin/web/project/framework/host/redirect.php"
php_value auto_prepend_file "/home/admin/web/project/framework/server.php"
```

and i want to :

```
# Example variable MY_PATH is = /home/admin/web/project/framework/
# and i use that variable, example
php_value auto_prepend_file "{MY_PATH}host/redirect.php"
php_value auto_prepend_file "{MY_PATH}server.php"
```

How to do that?

Comment: Aziz Alle Basyir Did you get any answer

Comment: @KiranMuralee, no.., i think, we can't :)

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31561191/htaccess-absolute-path ...

Comment: @reinierpost, yea, this old question, dont rlly care about this old code LOL