# Setting a variable inside .htaccess file XAMPP Windows

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp

I am currently working on a PHP project where I need to run some initial PHP code before every request.I searched on the web and came across the solution to use

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "path_to_project/session_check.php"
```

inside `.htaccess` file. This works perfectly , but I need to put the path to the project inside a variable, so I try to put it as an environment variable like

```
SetEnv PROJECT_PATH path_to_project
```

inside `.htaccess` file and tried to get the environmental variable inside same `.htaccess` file like

```
php_value auto_prepend_file %{PROJECT_PATH}/session_check.php
```

But this is not working. However I can access the same environmental variable inside PHP files with

```
getenv('PROJECT_PATH')
```

But not inside `.htaccess` file

I found a similar question already asked 1 year ago

[Variable in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46969411/variable-in-htaccess)

But was not answered.

Complete code inside `.htaccess` file is given below

```
SetEnv PROJECT_PATH path_to_project
php_value auto_prepend_file %{PROJECT_PATH}/session_check.php
```

Please note I am using XAMPP on Windows operating system.
Any help or alternate approach would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe is the "space" at the end of  %{PROJECT_PATH } ?

Comment: @SimonlucaLandi Sorry that was a typo in the question, I updated that