# How to get path in .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'd like to prepend a file that contains some constants in PHP,

```
# Relative to .htaccess (won't work for files in subdirectories)
php_value auto_prepend_file "../_prepend.php"

# Using full path (works)
php_value auto_prepend_file "/Users/GoldenJoe/Development/Web Services/MyApp/api/v1/_prepend.php"
```

Obviously, the full path won't work when I deploy. How can I define a relative path and still have files in subfolders work?

Edit: Obviously, none of the solutions in the top search result (linked) work with subdirectories. No effort from SO, as usual.

Comment: Possibly duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045445/auto-prepend-php-file-using-htaccess-relative-to-htaccess-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto prepend PHP file using htaccess relative to htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045445/auto-prepend-php-file-using-htaccess-relative-to-htaccess-file)

Comment: lol, two people just posting the first search result as "possible duplicate" within a minute. Never change SO.

Comment: @GoldenJoe - If the shoe fits... (The first comment isn't a close vote, just a comment though).

Comment: `php_value auto_prepend_file "_prepend.php"` should work fine and keep php file at same level as `.htaccess`. Web server cannot include file from parent directory of `DocumentRoot`.