# Safeguard files from direct access through .htaccess and php to check for session + user group

Tags: apache, .htaccess, file-access

I currently have the task of coding a way to ensure that non-logged in, as well as specific user-groups on my wp-installation do not have access to files in a folder.

For that I tried using an .htaccess file that redirects all requests to a checkUser.php (which itself checks for the active session of the user as well as its role).
Then it opens the link that is given through *readFile()*

Unfortunately this creates a loop as a new request goes to the .htaccess file and redirects it back to checkUser.php

I tried:
Creating a Cookie for the first redirect, when that Cookie exists - delete it

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://adress.com/checkUser.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !transfer [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://adress.com/checkUser.php?url=$1 [R=301,CO=transfer:1:adress.com:1]
    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} transfer [NC]
RewriteRule https://adress.com/wp-content/uploads/folder_to_protect/{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301,CO=transfer:1:adress.com:0]

</IfModule>
```

Cookie Creation works - deletion does not and I am not quite sure why

Additionally this is a not too safe way to go as you could catch on to the cookie creation and make one yourself to access the files even if it in theory would only be existent for a second or less.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.
Have a good day!

Comment: this could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045445/auto-prepend-php-file-using-htaccess-relative-to-htaccess-file

Comment: _"Unfortunately this creates a loop as a new request goes to the .htaccess file"_ - because you are making another HTTP request - instead of having readfile just read it from the _file system_.

Comment: Of course, thank you CBroe! Had a bit of a blind spot there. Thank you so much! :)